# How to check when/whether an offer on the XRP Ledger's DEX has been accepted/fully consumed? [XRP] [XRPL]

Tags: ripple, xrp

I've been testing out interacting with the XRP Ledger, coding in Python. I started coding some basic queries regarding the status of the XRP Ledger from scratch based on the XRPL documentation (available [here](https://xrpl.org/get-started-using-python.html)) but then discovered XRPL-PY (I've reviewed the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/XRPLF/xrpl-py) and the documentation [here](https://xrpl-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)) and have since been predominately using XRPL-PY to interact with the XRP Ledger given its general ease of use. I've been able to accomplish most of the basic types of interactions with the XRP Ledger one might want to do, including creating a wallet and submitting an offer to exchange one currency for another on the XRP Ledger (what I'll call an "Offer"). However, one point that I have been unable to figure out, whether by using XRPL-PY or interacting with the XRP Ledger directly, is how to determine when/whether a previously submitted Offer has been fully consumed (i.e., another transaction, or transactions, were submitted to the XRP Ledger that accepted my Offer such that it is no longer outstanding and the offered currencies were exchanged at the offered rate). This seems like a basic query that most people interacting with the XRP Ledger would want to be able to establish, but I haven't seen anything in the XRPL or XRPL-PY documentation explaining how to do it. My preference would be to be able to subscribe to updates from the XRPL Ledger such that it lets me know once my Offer has been partially or fully consumed, but if that's not possible I would like to at least be able to repeatedly query the status of my Offer from the XRP Ledger and know what will change in the response once my Offer has been partially or fully consumed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had your question answered on another channel so I will include this here just in case people will find this useful later. Cheers!

You have 3 options:

POLLING account_offers. You can use the sequence number to identify the offer
POLLING book_offer. You can use the "Account" and "Sequence" fields to identify the offer.
WS subscribing to "accounts" using the account you want to track. This is the most "complex" because you need to parse all the metadata for all validated transactions that involve the particular account but it's the best because it's asynchronous and via websocket.